# Can I travel to Germany alone?

Tags: air-travel, germany

I'm trying to travel with my friend (both 16 years old) to visit my relative in Germany. We are from Macedonia, and we have information that we cannot travel to Germany alone without older people with us. Our relatives will wait for us on the airport. Is it allowed to travel with plane without older people with us?

Do we need some additional documents to bring with us to Germany?

Comment: I don't know about Germany and Macedonia, but in Russia a minor can't exit the country alone. We went around that by getting a paper from a notary (in this case a Russian consulate) signed by my mother, that she allows me to travel alone. Check with Macedonian travel regulations regarding minors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, unaccompanied minors can travel by air but it has to be clear to the airline that the minor has parental consent (usually by one parent taking the child to the airport, or picking up the child at the other end).

Crossing borders as an unaccompanied minor may be a different matter, though.  The country you are entering may wonder if you are running away from your family.  You may need a notarized letter signed by both of your parents authorizing you to leave the country.  If there is any uncertainty about whether you need this, I would still have it as the risk of not having it is being returned home and not seeing your family in Germany.

Comment: Second this.  Get a notarized letter, ideally from both parents, indicating where you are going and that you have parental permission for the trip.

Answer (score 2):

Germany should have no issue with that, it is pretty common for people to travel alone with 15 or 16. I wouldn't know about the Macedonian side.

Answer (score -1):

Your airline will know. Also, airlines themselves may require that you are accompanied by an adult, especially the low budget ones.

Comment: I never heard of an airline that requires anyone over 16 to be accompanied by an adult. For example Wizz considers 16 years of age as a full blown adult: Children under 14 years old cannot fly unless accompanied by an adult at least 16 years of age.

Comment: An airline doesn't know the exact rules, but they can tell you whether they will allow you to board or not. And since it is very expensive for the airline to fly you to Germany, and having to take you back because you are refused entry, you can be quite confident that you will be allowed in if they let you board. No legal guarantee though.